# Issue when installing telnet on centos8

Tags: centos, telnet

I am trying to install telnet on a centos8 server but keep getting this error:

[image]

I have also used dnf command(`dnf install telnet`)  but get the same error message.

I use the following on line tutorial to install telnet:

https://geekflare.com/telnet-command-not-found/

Any idea what i am missing here please?

Comment: you might have not to use telnet ; therefore your problem here seems to be about the package name containing telnet method, `rpm -q --whatprovides  telnet` and I guess you're using quite modern centos so please use dnf instead of yum

Comment: @francoisP I have used  dnf install telnet and get same error message

Comment: please read the message & if it does'nt match (If I missed something) copy your real/exact error message ;)

Comment: `telnet` was provided in the `appstream` repo in CentOS 8 but since it's EOL, it's now in the vault repo. It's actually better to migrate the system to Alma Linux or Rocky Linux which are forks that are binary compatible.